# Canvas scaling images from iPhone iOS 6

Tags: canvas, mobile-safari, ios6, html5-canvas

I'm experiencing weird scaling issues trying to scale images uploaded from an iPhone using the  now available on iOS 6. I'm only having issue with images in the camera roll. Images in Photo Streams or downloaded from the web etc. work fine.

Same issue on both 3GS and 4S - so NOT RETINA related...!? Works fine on "the new iPad".

Using ctx.drawimage(0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,300,225) or something like that but the images are really stretched in width.

Only way I can get is sort of right is ctx.scale(1,3.5) which makes no sense to me. I've tried setting width and height on the canvas (attr and css), scaling to devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio and anything else I can google up :-/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way the image is going to get stretched is if the ratio you're using to copy from the source is different to the ratio you're using to copy to the destination.

In the following, what are the values of `img.width` and `img.height`?

```
ctx.drawimage(resource, 0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,300,225)
```

Is the ratio between these two values the same as what is between 300, and 225?

Comment: I think your absolutely right. I did try to detect the image width and height and then scale appropriately, but I probably had some bug. I ended up using phonegap for this project, and phonegap's camera library supports specifying your required scale.